What exactly is the extension of a binary relation?
I have a serious doubt about what is the extension of a relation.
The question
If I have a binary relation $R \subset A\times B$, it is often said that

the extension of $R$ is a subset of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $R(a,b)$ is true,
and where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$;

but isn't this the same as saying that $R$ is such a set? Why talk about an “extension” of $R$? And what about the general case of an $n$-ary relation?
My interpretation
This is what I can intuit about it (most likely I am wrong):
In set theory an $n$-ary relation is defined as a subset of the cartesian product of any $n$ sets. This means that, in principle, a relation is a set of $n$-tuples. Although this is not the case when $R$ is unary, here its elements may not necessarily be $n$-tuples, for it just happens that $R\subset A$, with $A$ an arbitrary set. This being so, what is the most general definition of a relation? This on the one hand.
Now, as for the term “extension”, I think the following: in reality, relations are special functions that go from any set $A$ to the set $\{T, F\}$ ($T$ means true, $F$ means false) and it is only when we decide which set $A$ we are going to consider, that we can speak of the extension of $R$. For example, if $R(x):=x$ is an even number, the extension of $R$ over $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ would be $\{2,4\}$, while $R=\{(1,F),(2,T),(3,F),(4,T),(5,F)\}$.
Why do I ask this?
It turns out that the doubt came to me after I started reading Peter Smith's Beginning Mathematical Logic: A Study Guide book, specifically on page 9 of the latest version. This is part of a chapter on things we should already know about sets:

Next, we add to these basics the standard set-theoretic treatment of  relations and functions:
(iv) If $R$ is a binary relation between members of the set $A$ and
members of the set $B$, then its extension is the set of ordered pairs
$\langle x, y\rangle$ (with $x\in A$ and $y\in B$) such that $x$ is
$R$ to $y$. So the extension of $R$ is a subset of $A\times B$.
Similarly, the extension of an $n$-place relation is the set of
$n$-tuples of things which stand in that relation. In the unary case,
where $P$ is a property defined over some set $A$, then we can simply
say that the extension of $P$ is the set of members of $A$ which are
$P$.
For many purposes, it is mostly harmless to simply identify a
property or relation with its extension-as-a-set.
(v) The extension (or graph) of a unary function $f$ which sends
members of $A$ to members of $B$ is the set of ordered pairs $\langle x, y\rangle$ (with $x\in A$ and $y\in B$) such that $f(x) = y$.
Similarly for $n$-place functions. Again, for many purposes, we can
harmlessly identify a function with its graph.

I am an undergraduate student of mathematics and I am very interested in the study of logic, but I had never heard of this thing that I am supposed to know.... I wonder if I'm missing something important or it's just something I'll learn later and I shouldn't worry about it for now.
I would very much appreciate any comments or answers that would clear up my confusion.

Typically "extension " is used in the context of formal languages, where we give the syntax (a relation symbol) and then define a semantics (the extension) for it.

So possibly the reference you got it from was saying that $R$ was a binary relation symbol which by itself is meaningless, and then defining an extension for this symbol only gives it its meaning as a binary relation in the first place and thus is not repeating anything.

The extension of a predicete/relation is the set of objects satisfying it. Thus, the "extension" of a set is the set itself.

If you gave a source, we could likely provide much better answers.

@MichaelCarey Yes, I already edited the question to give a little more context.

@Karl Yes, sorry, it was a typo. I have corrected it.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Does that mean that relations are ultimately predicates and not necessarily sets?

Here, "extension" is as in "(axiom of) extensionality". It does not mean "the result of extending". It is closer in meaning to "extent".

@ZhenLin That makes a lot more sense.

Re. Your edit - Turns out the author is around here, so with any luck you can just get the answer from him directly :) https://math.stackexchange.com/users/35151/peter-smith

Some general points about relations and their extensions. To keep things simple, concentrate on binary relations.
(A) First a reminder that the notion of a relation is very general, of course applying mostly outside mathematics. Thus there is a relation of loving, the relation that Romeo has to Juliet if and only if he loves her. There is a relation of being north of, the relation that Cambridge has to Oxford if and only the first is north of the second. And so on.
What can we say about binary relations in general? Here's one thought. It is of the nature of a binary relation that it holds of or fails to hold of things. Frege famously put the point using this metaphor: a binary relation is 'unsaturated', having (as it were) two slots in it waiting to be filled by appropriate objects to give us a truth or falsehood. That's reflected linguistically by an expression for a binary relation (as it might be '... loves ---', or '... is north of ---') coming with two places which need to be filled by terms to get an atomic  sentence.
(B) Now turn to mathematics. You already know in fact that not every relation has an extension (so we can't identify relations with extensions across the board). For example take the relation of set-membership. Then there is no set of ordered pairs $\hat{E}$ such that $\langle x, y\rangle \in \hat{E}$ if and only if $x \in y$.  There are too many such pairs to form a set (on standard set theories).
(C) One counter-example is enough to defeat a universal claim that relations can be identified with their extensions. But you might think that relations which are 'too big' are special cases, requiring special treatment. So let's put that first point aside. So next note that treating a relation as a set of ordered pairs involves arbitrary choices of implementation scheme.

It is arbitrary to fix on e.g. Kuratowski's implementation of pairs.
Other set-theoretic pairing chemes will work equally well.

Even relative to a choice of pairing scheme, we could equally well
model a relation by the set of pairs $\langle y, x\rangle$ where
$xRy$, rather than by the set of pairs $\langle x, y\rangle$. And
again other choices are possible.


However, if various permutations of choices at stages (1) and (2) are pretty much as workable as each other, then we surely can't suppose that -- when we choose to equate a relation with its extension as conventionally defined-- we have made the uniquely right choice, i.e. the choice that correctly identifies which set that relation 'really' is.  And if there is no fact of the matter about which set a given relation is, then we can't flat-out identify the relation with its conventional extension.
(D)  But we can dig still deeper: the key observation is that a relation and its extension belong to different logical types -- and that is fundamentally why they can't be identical. As noted in (A), a binary relation is of its nature a gadget that takes a couple of objects to produce a truth or falsehood. By contrast a given set doesn't, of its nature, take a pair of objects or output a truth or falsehood. And what holds of sets in general holds of extensions in particular.
(E)  Which of course isn't to deny that we can make use of the extension of a relation  (a glorified look-up table) in mapping an mapping a pair of objects to a truth-value. Thus given $R$'s extension $\hat{R}$, we can say $xRy$ if and only if $\langle x, y\rangle \in \hat{R}$. But note, this is to specify one relation $R$ as a relation (not an extension!) in terms of another relation $\in$, where we can't eliminate the second relation in favour of an extension as noted in (B).
(F) So where does all this get us? It cautions against baldly identifying relations with their (set-theoretic) extensions. But for many purposes -- as hinted in my remark quoted by the OP -- we can usefully implement relations by their extensions, or take extensions as proxies or surrogates or representations for relations, whichever idiom you prefer. (I don't want to deny that for a moment!)
But it is very important, I think, to note (sooner or later) that we are in the implementation game here, and so the door is left open to the idea that their could be other ways of implementing relations in other foundational frameworks (e.g. type-theoretic, categorical ...). Falling in too quickly with an outright identification of relations with their extensions (or functions with their graphs) is in danger of (wrongly) making alternative non-set-theoretic foundations look to be non-starters.

Two interpretations:

Typically "extension" is used in the context of formal languages, where we give the syntax (a relation symbol) and then define a semantics (the extension) for it. So possibly the reference you got it from was saying that $R$ was a binary relation symbol which by itself is meaningless, and then defining an extension for this symbol only gives it its meaning as a binary relation in the first place and thus is not repeating anything.

With the quote you provided, the author may be hinting at the difference between the extension (= the real world objects which the relation encompasses, such as $\{\langle 0, 1 \rangle, \langle 0, 2 \rangle, \ldots, \langle 1, 2 \rangle, \ldots\}$) and the intension (= the conceptual content, such as "is less than", or for functions something like "the computation which transforms its input into the double") as two kinds of semantics.



I don't think the author was hinting at (2) ...

The key to understanding is (I think) in the second-last paragraph in your quoted text.
Personally, I think this is easiest to think about in more type theoretic terms. You could imagine this is because the set theory and its logic is being described in a  logical framework, but perhaps that is not the only interpretation. Also, I'm going to make the set theory a bit more 'structural' than is typical, because that will help force the distinction. So, we have something like:

Two basic types $\newcommand{\Set}{\mathsf{Set}} \Set$ and $\newcommand{\Prop}{\mathsf{Prop}} \Prop$
Logical connectives for building compound propositions, like $∧ : \Prop → \Prop → \Prop$
Quantifiers like $∀ : (\Set → \Prop) → \Prop$
For each $A : \Set$ a type $\newcommand{\El}{\mathsf{El}} \El(A)$ of its elements
Ways of forming sets, like comprehension: $\{|\} : (A : \Set) → (\El(A) → \Prop) → \Set$

Note that these $→$ arrows are in the type theory, and they allow presenting the structure of the set theory in terms of how the two sorts are mutually built up in a sort of higher-order way, using the type theory for variable binding, rather than getting into very syntactic details. The 'structural' bit is $\El$, where there may not necessarily be a notion of $\Set$s belonging to other $\Set$s, only of the type $\El(A)$ of elments of a set $A$.
Now, in comprehension, we see what might be called in this system a "predicate on $A$". It is a value of $\El(A) → \Prop$ in the type theory. In a more traditional first-order logic presentation, this would probably be a formula with one free variable, but here we can be be a bit more agnostic. It is just whatever is classified in the type theory as a 'mapping' from elements of $A$ to propositions.
Comprehension says that given a set $A$ and a predicate on $A$, we can form the set of elements of $A$ satisfying the predicate. Or at least, it gives a name for such a thing; there would need to be other rules characterizing what it's like.
In particular a predicate is not a set, nor an element of a set. Comprehension (when fleshed out) says that there is (part of) a correspondence between predicates $\El(A) → \Prop$ and subsets of $A$, which could be called the "extension" of the predicate in line with your book. Here, a subset is a set $A'$ with a mapping $\El(A') → \El(A)$ with the right properties (injectivity). Comprehension gives the subset $\{x \in A | P(x) \} : \Set$ corresponding to $P : A → \Prop$.
Similarly, a relation between $A : \Set$ and $B : \Set$ is not a set. It is, in this framework, a value of $\El(A) → \El(B) → \Prop$. Comprehension would again give a correspondence between relations in this sense and subsets of $A × B$, and the subset is what your book is calling the "extension" of the relation.
So, when you say:

If I have a binary relation $R⊂A×B$ ...

This is (under this methodology) wrong. The subset is the extension of the relation.
Now, it is typical for set theorists to say that a binary relation is a subset of $A×B$. This is because of the fact in the quoted text:

For many purposes, it is mostly harmless to simply identify a property or relation with its extension-as-a-set.

This is because when most people work in set theory, there is a complete correspondence between relations in the $\El(A) → \El(B) → \Prop$ sense and subsets. Comprehension gets you a subset from any predicate, and something like:
$$λ a\ b. ∃r \in R. ι(r) = (a, b)$$
is the corresponding relation of a subset $R$ of $A×B$, with $ι : \El(R) → \El(A×B)$ the inclusion witnessing the subset. Also, set theories with the power set axiom will have a set $Ω$ such that there is a correspondence between elements of $Ω^{A×B}$ and relations from $A$ to $B$. So they can get away with talking only about sets, because everything in the type theory we have been discussing has a reflection within the theory.
However, you may want to consider a weaker theory. For instance, Kripke-Platek set theory does not have a power set axiom, and it only allows comprehension of $Δ_0$ formulas. So, our type for comprehension above is wrong; we'd need to have a more refined type than $\Prop$ with more limited quantifiers. In this case, it is not even a given that every relation has an extension. We can still consider relations in the $\El(A) → \El(B) → \Prop$ sense, but not all of them need correspond to subsets of $A × B$ (or values of a power set). So it no longer makes sense to conflate the two, and which relations have extensions could be a significant thing to investigate.
One reason you might want to do this is that being able to reflect all relations within the theory is very powerful, and makes it difficult to analyze. Kripke-Platek set theory is often used as a basis for doing things like ordinal analysis of analogues of large cardinal axioms. To my knowledge, we are nowhere near being able to do similar analyses of plain ZF.
Since you're reading a book about logic, it seems natural that it would want to pay attention to these distinctions, because it may want to talk about weaker, stratified theories like this, and not just assume the ZF(C)-like scenario where it's possible to talk purely in terms of internal reflections of the logical structure. And I suppose, if you're going to learn the details of logic, you should be made aware that distinctions like this exist, even if it's not necessary to pay attention to them in many cases.
If you want, you can even recognize this distinction within a ZF-like set theory. This is similar to what you said. Say a relation between $A$ and $B$ actually is an element of $Ω^{A×B}$ (where, for ZF, $Ω$ is a 2-element set). Then, there is a correspondence between these relations and subsets $R \subseteq A×B$. This is actually a way of characterizing $Ω$. This correspondence (for arbitrary exponents, not just products) makes it a subobject classifier. The other sense of distinguishing between relations and subsets is a sort of (partially) meta-level version of this.

As another example of how this point of view can be useful, in the definition of a topological space, purely ZFC-based presentations have to make do with making it a set $X$ and an element $\mathcal{T} \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$ satisfying certain conditions -- which commonly leads to confusion in beginners to the study of topology.  I'd argue it's more useful to view a topological space as consisting of a type $X$ of points, and an openness predicate $\mathsf{open} : \mathcal{P}(X) \to \mathsf{Prop}$.

To the present answers and comments, I wish to add a rather philosopically-inclined perspective. I hope the discussion below will help those who have begun to tackle model theory and feel some leaps in the introductory definitions. Possibly, the textbook authors view such points as digressions and leave their grasp to the reader's progress in the area. I suppose, Peter Smith who is also a contibuter to this site, is one of the few who remarks such a fine distinction. Concerning what follows, some terminology varies from one author to another, but the ideas are easily recognisable.
Consider a formal language $\mathcal{L}$. The logical vocabulary contituent of $\mathcal{L}$ is that of the logical system one has chosen to use, e.g., first-order predicate logic, propositional modal logic, etc. The non-logical vocabulary is its signature. Typically, the signature is expressed as a sequence of symbols for relations, functions and individual constants:
$$\langle R_{1}, R_{2},\ldots, R_{i}, f_{1}, f_{2},\ldots, f_{j},c_{1}, c_{2},\ldots, c_{k}\rangle$$
An  $\mathcal{L}$-structure (to be used as models for formulas and theories) consists of a non-empty universe of discourse $\mathrm{A}$ and an interpretation function $\mathrm{I}$ that assigns an interpretation to the relations, functions and individual constants in the universe of discourse. Thus, a structure is represented with a plain schema (putting bold font for sequences) as
$$\mathfrak{A}=\langle\mathrm{A},\mathbf{R}^{\mathfrak{A}}, \mathbf{f}^{\mathfrak{A}},\mathbf{c}^{\mathfrak{A}}\rangle$$
For example, the signature $\sigma=\langle <, +,\cdot, 0, 1\rangle$ in which $<$ is a binary relation symbol, $+$ and $\cdot$ are binary function symbols, $0$ and $1$ are constant symbols, induces the following two familiar structures:
$$\mathfrak{R}=\langle\mathbb{R},<^{\mathfrak{R}},+^{\mathfrak{R}},\cdot^{\mathfrak{R}}, 0^{\mathfrak{R}}, 1^{\mathfrak{R}}\rangle$$
and
$$\mathfrak{Q}=\langle\mathbb{Q},<^{\mathfrak{Q}},+^{\mathfrak{Q}},\cdot^{\mathfrak{Q}}, 0^{\mathfrak{Q}}, 1^{\mathfrak{Q}}\rangle$$
where $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers and $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of rational numbers, and $<, +, \cdot, 0, 1$ are interpreted in the ordinary fashion.
Let us look closer at the extensional aspect of the structures. To illustrate, we take a modular arithmetic structure $\mathfrak{M}$ with the modulus 4 and a universe of discourse $\mathrm{M}=\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$. The signature contains the congruence relation $\equiv$, the functions $\cdot$ and $+$, all as defined in modular arithmetic. We distinguish $0$ and $1$ as individual constants:
$$\mathfrak{M}=\langle\mathrm{M},\equiv^{\mathfrak{M}}, \cdot^{\mathfrak{M}},+^{\mathfrak{M}}, 0^{\mathfrak{M}}, 1^{\mathfrak{M}}\rangle$$
Then,
$$\equiv^{\mathfrak{M}}=\{(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (4, 0), (0, 4), (5, 5), (5, 1), (1, 5), (6, 6), (6, 2), (2, 6)\}$$
Notice that there is no restriction on the universe to be choosen and the interpretation to be fixed (even, possibly of no import, a structure only with a universe and null relations, functions and constants is not ruled out). So, it may be a dull, but not an intricate exercise to conjure up many  coinciding structures. Imagine we build a set of meaningless symbols, and interpret $+$ as $\dagger$, $\cdot$ as $\ddagger$, and so on. Meanwhile, from the viewpoint of sets which are regarded as purely extensional, structureless collections, such related structures as $\mathfrak{Q}$ and $\mathfrak{R}$ appear unconnected. Thus, the notion of signature starts to seem useless and the element of interpretation to lose significance in formally investigating validity (recall that a formula $\phi$ is valid if and only if $\phi$ yields a true statement under each possible interpretation of $\phi$).
That is where unmentioned intensional aspect manifests itself. We have a prior, generic understanding of, for example, the signature $\langle <, +,\cdot, 0, 1\rangle$. We interpret it in various contexts with respect to this understanding. That is, we have a prior conception of addition, multiplication, etc. In the traditional terminology of logic, these are called intensions. They determine their correlative extensions, the objects which they can be applied.
A few concluding remarks may be helpful for those whole to follow up the subject:
Intension and extension are actually two modes of meaning of a term that denotes a concept. Relatively to each other, the intension can be said to abstract, the extension to concretise the term.
The term 'intension' had faded away from the vocabulary of logic,and to my knowldge, was revived by Rudolf Carnap. The new usage, as in 'intensional logic' has a related, but different sense than the traditional one; it signifies a more dependent sense contrasting with 'classical extensional' than the independent traditional sense. I believe both are useful.
